# Configuration selection group get selection value

Tags: c#

I have some problem with getting config info, how to get `isUpdatable` value for some value test1 or test2, or test3 if paramiter will get outside.

I have this sample in config.

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name ="UpdateSettings">
  <section name="test1" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  <section name="test2" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  <section name="test3" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<UpdateSettings>
<test1>
  <add key="isUpdatable" value="0"/> <!-- get from service - 1, get from config - 0,-->
</test1>
<test2>
  <add key="isUpdatable" value="1"/>
</test2>
<test3>
  <add key="isUpdatable" value="1"/>
</test3>
</UpdateSettings>
```

And this peace of C# code

```
  name = "test1";
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
  ConfigurationSectionGroup UpdateSettings = config.GetSectionGroup("UpdateSettings");
  /* this is Connect beetwen selection group and selection, but how?*/        
  NameValueCollection sectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(name) as NameValueCollection;
  var value = sectionSettings["isUpdatable"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, you have array of values so `sectionSettings[0]` will get you first one and `sectionSettings[1]` second one and so on.

```
  name = "test1";
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
  ConfigurationSectionGroup UpdateSettings = config.GetSectionGroup("UpdateSettings");        
  NameValueCollection sectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(name) as NameValueCollection;
  var value = sectionSettings[0]["isUpdatable"];
```

Comment: I don't want to connect to index - i want to connect up to name!